# registering browser google chrome extension for resize event

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

I'm new to google chrome extension development. i want to register my extension javascript to listen for the browser resize event. How can i do this ?

Currently

```
window.addEventListener("load",myfunction,false);
```

in the extension javascript was able to execute myfunction when i launch the browser

but

```
window.addEventListener("resize",customfunction,false);
```

doesnt execute customfunction on browser window resize..

How can we fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is using the following in a content script:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
     console.log("Resized");
};
```

This will log "Resized" to your console every time you resize the window. With that in mind, you can look into [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html), which you could use to send a message to your `popup.js` (or other background script) anytime the window has been resized, and then you can handle it accordingly. Also, apparently adding this functionality by way of `chrome.windows.onResize` is still an [in-progress bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44464).

Comment: @user1668527 Yes, that was inside of a basic `popup.js` that was referenced in my `popup.html`. I haven't tested it, but I imagine it would work using content scripts as well. I can test later if you'd like.

Comment: @user1668527 Sure - I'll update with a very basic content script that just logs 'Resized' to the console every time you resize the window. Obviously that is kind of worthless in itself, but you can then use Message Passing (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to pass information back and forth between your content script and background page, which I imagine is what you want.